# transform a picture inside of a tkinter canvas in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

how do I transform a picture inside of a tkinter canvas in Python ? For example to apply a b&w filter on it ? Thank you ! I'm a very new beginner and have to do this project for my final exam :)

Comment: I don't think Tkinter has that kind of capability. Consider using a dedicated image manipulation library, such as Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas doesn't allow transformation.
It is OpenCV that you should use. You can download from the folowing link:
https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/ (I would prefer writing the procedure in the answer. But, this one is long. So, pls co-operate)

It has some amazing functions for transformations. Refer to the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

Hope this helps..